# Не могу переустановить MySQL 5.7 на Ubuntu Server 16.04.1

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, веб-сервер, mariadb

Был установлен mariaDB 10. 
Все снес.

полное удаление mariaDB UBUNTU 
(для Debian пути и команды могут отличаться)

```
 apt-get --purge remove mariadb*
 apt-get autoremove
 apt-get autoclean
```

если возникают ошибки при удалении - 
заходим в папку `/var/lib/dpkg/info`
и удаляем там всё что начинается на mariadb и на mysql
повторяем предыдущие три команды

после желательно

```
 apt-get --purge remove mysql*
 apt-get autoremove
 apt-get autoclean
```

убедившись что в `/var/lib/dpkg/info` ничего не осталось - 
удаляем папку `/etc/mysql`
удаляем папку `/var/lib/mysql` ВНИМАНИЕ здесь хранятся все ваши базы так что если нужно их оставить - переименуйте папку и после установки mysql скопируйте в новую - ТОЛЬКО те которые вы создавали самостоятельно (без системных)

теперь не забудьте почистить источник репозитория mariaDB который вы добавляли при её установке, 
здесь `nano /etc/apt/sources.list`
иначе при попытке установить чистый мускуль увидете как ставятся пакеты от марии, и придётся начинать удаление сначала по тому что получите ошибку при установке. :(

перед установкой MySql выполните

```
 apt-get update
 apt-get upgrade
```

потом как обычно  `apt-get install mysql-server`
при этом установка может не спросить пароль для root, а подхватит существующий
проверить установку можно командой 
`service mysql status`
далее
 `apt-get install phpmyadmin` (если нужно)

Ошибок в итоге не было.

Ставил:

```
# sudo apt-get install mysql-server

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libevent-core-2.0-5 mysql-server-5.7 mysql-server-core-5.7
Suggested packages:
  tinyca
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libevent-core-2.0-5 mysql-server mysql-server-5.7 mysql-server-core-5.7
0 upgraded, 4 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/10.1 MB of archives.
After this operation, 94.7 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously unselected package libevent-core-2.0-5:amd64.
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'mysql-client' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
(Reading database ... 169368 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libevent-core-2.0-5_2.0.21-stable-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libevent-core-2.0-5:amd64 (2.0.21-stable-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server-core-5.7.
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server-core-5.7_5.7.16-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-server-core-5.7 (5.7.16-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server-5.7.
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server-5.7_5.7.16-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.16-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server.
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server_5.7.16-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-server (5.7.16-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
ureadahead will be reprofiled on next reboot
Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu12) ...
Setting up libevent-core-2.0-5:amd64 (2.0.21-stable-2) ...
Setting up mysql-server-core-5.7 (5.7.16-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Setting up mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.16-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-server-5.7.postinst: line 143: /usr/share/mysql-common/configure-symlinks: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.7 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.7; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.7 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu4) ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu12) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.7
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: [/var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-server-5.7.postinst: line 143: /usr/share/mysql-common/configure-symlinks: No such file or directory](http://askubuntu.com/a/773443/416190)

Comment: Спасибо не помогает.

Comment: dpkg: dependency problems prevent removal of mysql-common:
 mysql-client-5.7 depends on mysql-common (>= 5.5).
 mysql-server-5.7 depends on mysql-common (>= 5.6.22-1~).
 mysql-server-5.7 depends on mysql-common (>= 5.5).
 mysql-server-5.7 depends on mysql-common (>= 5.6.22-1~).
 mysql-server-5.7 depends on mysql-common (>= 5.5).
 libmysqlclient20:amd64 depends on mysql-common (>= 5.5).

dpkg: error processing package mysql-common (--remove):
 dependency problems - not removing
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-common

Comment: ну, перечислите все эти пакеты в **одной** команде. что-нибудь вроде `$ sudo aptitude remove "~imysql" `

Comment: sudo apt-get --purge remove mariadb-client*

sudo apt-get --purge remove common-client*

sudo apt-get --purge remove mysql-server*

sudo apt-get --purge remove mysql-client*

sudo apt-get --purge autoremove

sudo apt-get autoclean Все удалил.